# How to make image upload directly while choosing image rather than pressing upload button in JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

How to make the script to make upload file rather than pressing upload button in the below script

### Detail :

In the below the `<input type="file" id="pImage" name="image" class="upload-img" style="opacity:0">` will display the image that is uploaded and the `<input name="image" type="file"/>` to choose the file. and `<button>Upload</button>` to upload the image.

And in the `<input type="file" id="pImage" name="image" class="upload-img" style="opacity:0">` it will choose the file, But i don't want to upload the image every time after clicking on the `Upload button` How can make the image upload while choosing the file itself

**HTML :**

```
<div id="image" class="upload-img-span"></div>
<input type="file" id="pImage" name="image" class="upload-img" style="opacity:0">
<span class="upload-txt-span">Upload Img</span>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<td colspan="4" align="left">
<input name="image" type="file"/>
<button>Upload</button>
```

**Script :**

```
<script>
$("form#data").submit(function(){
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'globalimageupload',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) 
        {
               $('#image').html(data);
              console.log(data)
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: I would say it's bad practice to do this. You should let the user initiate it.

Comment: I mean you think, having the upload button is better way ??

Comment: Yes, so the user is choosing to submit the form.

Comment: Yes, understand,, But it happened the situation where the upload button is not required.

Comment: What if the user selects the wrong file and wants to change it, but the upload has already started? In situations like this, the user should have control.

Comment: IF the user selects wrong file, they can choose another file, (Yes but the file chosen already will be uploaded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I Solved it by Triggering the function inside the own function

i.e.,

```
$("input[type='file']").on("change", function() 
    {
        $("form#data").submit();
});
```

**And the modified script is**

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() 
 {
 $("form#data").submit(function(){
 var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
 $.ajax({
    url: 'globalimageupload',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: true,
    success: function (data) 
    {
           $('#image').html(data);
          console.log(data);            
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
    });
    return false;
});
$("input[type='file']").on("change", function() 
 {
        $("form#data").submit();
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you exactly want but take a look at .trigger() docs are [here](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/). By this you can trigger any other event, say click of upload in your case.Hope it helps

Comment: Should i use $("form#data").click(image(){.. ?

Answer (score 0):

By using following code i think it will solve your problem,

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery File Upload Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="server/php/" multiple>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
        });
    }
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

For more information please visit followin link,
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin

Answer (score 0):

In order to pull this off, you'll need to initiate the function with something other than `.submit()`.

```
<script>
$('input[type=file]').change(function() { 
    $("form#data").submit(function(){
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'globalimageupload',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) 
            {
                   $('#image').html(data);
                  console.log(data)
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

With this method, when the user chooses a file it should start the upload automatically.

Comment: I tried your answer, , I mean added $('input[type=file]').change(function() {  before the  $("form#data").submit(function(){ .. But it didn't work :(

Comment: I believe you'll need to output the form objects using console.log to make sure they are being selected properly. For example `console.log("form#data");` inside submit function then look in console tab of developer tools to make sure it is the correct object. Keep doing this to make sure they are all correct. Also check the network tab to find out if the form is submitting.

Comment: While i do console.log("form#data"); it didn't print any data in the console

Comment: If it doesn't put anything there, it means that the function before it is not starting successfully. More than likely because JQuery cannot find the selector. http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/traversing/

Comment: Thanks, However i have added my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26881254/3492495

Answer (score 0):

try this :
**php file** :file_path.php

print_r($_FILES['user_image']);

```js
$('#click_img_btn').click(function() {
   $('#image_fl_upload').click();
  });
  $('#image_fl_upload').change(function() {
   var formData = new FormData($('#image_up')[0]);
   $.ajax({
    url: 'file_path.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    success: function (data) 
    {
        
       alert(data);
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
   });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" name="save_user_photo1" id="image_up" class="profile_photo_upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                           
                           <input id="image_fl_upload" type="file" name="user_image" style="visibility:hidden" />
                           <input id="click_img_btn" name="save_user_photo" class="btn_change" type="button"  value="change"/>
                         </form>
```